# stopPropagation(); doesnt work to stop top of this child div

Tags: jquery, events, html, parent-child, stoppropagation

problem between parent and child DIV. when u click on child div will show up same as parent div. i want child div not follow parent div action. i tried stopPropagation() is not work or maybe im confuse.

html code:

```
<div class="innerbox">
<div id="button"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function ShowHide(d){
    $("div#button").click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       return;
    });

    //$(".innerbox").click(function(e) {
        jQuery(d).animate({"height": "toggle"}, {
            duration: 500,
            complete: function() {
                //add action after complete action...
            }
        });
    //});
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are doing given the partial code, but it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/gcpnc/

Comment: Is `$(".innerbox").click(` supposed to be commented out?

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you edit and clarify? I *think* you're trying to say that when the "innerbox" `div` is clicked, you want to animate it, but you don't want the "#button" div to be animated. If so, you'll have to move the "#button" `div` out of the "innerbox" div, as the child element is going to be affected by animation on its parent.

Comment: i did remove comment "$(".innerbox").click(" but it's something wrong with like bounce back like close close then double open.. i tried put with comment. its good proper animate but click button always follow parent div action.. its weird. =/ im gnna try find it out something wrong.

Comment: @user: It's not weird that the button follows the parent div, that's what child elements *do* (unless there's some absolute positioning going on you haven't shown). As for the double actions and such, I expect you're calling `ShowHide` more than once. You only want to hook up the event handler once, not multiple times.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: ah yeah but how can get value of 'd' without function? i did put ShowHide(<nameofdiv>); in their onclick.

Comment: @user: That would be fine, if you didn't then hook up an event handler within the function. The `onclick` attribute sets up an event handler. But your handler is *also* setting up an event handler, so you probably don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saing that when the ".innerbox" `div` is clicked, you want to animate it, but you don't want the "#button" div to be animated, you'll have to move the "#button" `div` out of the ".innerbox" `div`, as a child element is going to be affected by animation on its parent.

`stopPropagation` is about stopping the event itself bubbling up to ancestor elements, not the effects of what you do. Certainly in that case, the `click` event is being stopped and not sent onto the ".innerbox" `div`.

---

This may be off-topic, but when/how do you call `ShowHide`? Because you're hooking up an event handler within the function; a new handler will be attached *every time you call `ShowHide`*. I don't think that's likely what you want...

Comment: well i have no choice to follow your instruct. Thanks.